# Trigger git commit using form response

Tags: javascript, git, forms, github, github-api

is there a way that I can trigger a git commit when a user submits their js form? I want to include the data submitted in the form in the description of the commit on github. I tried using multiple frameworks, but I didn't succeed.

Stack:

- Im using bootstrap 5.1 for the ui.
- Deploying on a static site on render.com

Comment: It depends on what your app is, if you have a backend to send the form to I would just prepare a bash script that executes `git add bla bla bla` and `git commit -m "$FORMDATA"` and execute that when a new form is sent. Try giving more information on your application, where the form is located, how it is handled by your backend and so son. This information is not enough to answer

Comment: Please Add Some more information .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using PHP, you can use the `exec` to execute a command.

Basically, you can write a REST API that will run the [`exec`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) functions.

For example, let's use Laravel

```
Route::post('commit', function(Request $request) {
  exec('cd /to/your/folder';
  exec('git add .');
  exec('git commit -m "'.$request->commitMessage.'"');
  exec('git push origin master');
});
```